# Delay page processing for some seconds

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 .I have a ajax timer control on master page which is continue running, on my content page i have 3 text box control and a submit button. i want to delay the page processing for 20 second whenever anybody click on submit button but timer should not stop it should keep running. how to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Thread.Sleep()?  What do you mean by delay page processing?  Server side or client side.  Is this for debugging purposes?

Comment: so you would delay page postback or actual server side logic execution?

Comment: Thanx for reply but Thread.Sleep() stop whole application for few seconds and in that case timer too stop i want timer to be running, and all my code are written on server side nothing is on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `Timer1.Enabled = false;` in finally block

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           // your code ............
        }
        catch
        {             
        }
        finally
        {
            divLoading.Visible = false;
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what you need here - but what I think you're asking for is you'd like a button to be clicked on the client side, have a 20 second wait period on the client side while your timer is still running, then submit the page for processing.  If this is what you want it has to be fully client driven - the timer isn't "running" in the server code.  This is all based on the assumption that you're talking about an AJAX timer...

If this is what you're asking for, the following code should get you there:

```
        function onButtonClick(e) {
            var evt = Sys.UI.DomEvent.isInstanceOfType(e) ? e : new Sys.UI.DomEvent(e);
            if(evt.target["_doClick"] === true) {
                // just let the event happen 
                // (still w/ button disabled to prevent double click)
                evt.target["disabled"] = "disabled";
                evt.target["_doClick"] = false;
                alert('the real click');
            } else {
                evt.target["disabled"] = "disabled";
                evt.target["_doClick"] = true;
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                var t = evt.target;
                setTimeout(function () { t["disabled"] = ""; t.click(); }, 20000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanx for your reply but all my code is on server side , the submit button is actually a server side button control and on click event of that button i want processing of page  to be wait or halt for some seconds but timer should be keep running.

Comment: Hi Vicky - if you're running an ASP.NET Ajax timer, what is actually happening is the control is emitting the javascript required to repeatedly invoke an action from the client side. If you want to delay the processing on the server side you can invoke System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000) but I would not recommend this approach.  You're far better off updating the onButtonClick to return false and place OnClientClick="return onButtonClick(window.event)" either in your presentation file or from your code-behind.  This way you block on the client, not the server...

Comment: Vicky - in reading your other responses, I can't stress enough that in ASP.NET anything that's happening in the browser is not server side.  Your timer isn't "running" on the server.  The server isn't counting seconds before firing.  The CLIENT is counting seconds before firing - all the server is doing is emitting the client side code to create the timer - if you want to allow the timer to continue running, you have to handle this from the client side and delay the postback, or you have to block the thread on the server, which is not going to be pretty under load.

Comment: hi Brian you are right with every word, i used your code but it giving me exception : Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0
Source File: http://localhost:4810/Datasolution/ScriptResource.axd?d=vKtHWnzMC_2Uk74_uhDe7fSk8sbHoyGgnkNlhYamto7-NJ_rELZ08AXuXRzf1ad9BgSOCPHma4GBZZEmGh6lYZM1rJxkIMLaa6gyIoHnR6EEmk9Srs2O9Z36tRKwxrV16MkaqksaR1JWh3KS3QTxHvGbUB81&t=11e6618b
Line: 1410